Les armes à poudre noire dans *Le Clos du Roi*
Dans le livre Le Clos du Roi par Marcel Scipion, dans le chapitre Mon premier coup de fusil à piston, il parle d'un 'fusil à piston', apparemment un autre nom pour un fusil à percussion.
Ensuite il mentionne 'un fusil à broche' et je crois que c'est ce qu'on appelle en anglais 'pinfire'.
Mais après il parle des 'fusils à 'chiens', et là, je suis perdu — j'aurais dit que toutes les armes à poudre noire ont des chiens ...
"Le fusil à piston était le résultat d’une invention
remarquable qui détrôna le fusil à silex. Celui-ci ne
pouvait être utilisé les jours de vent, l’étincelle contra-
riée n’atteignant pas la poudre. Or, la Provence est
assez ventée, comme chacun sait. Le piston fut
accueilli par les chasseurs de la génération du grand-
père comme la plus géniale des inventions. Quelques
dizaines d’années plus tard, sournoisement, le fusil
à broche tenta de le supplanter, mais n’y parvint pas.
Il fallut attendre encore cinquante ans pour que les
fusils à « chiens » lui retirent un peu de sa vogue.
Mais il fut définitivement cloué au mur par le moderne
fusil à percussion centrale ..."
Ça donne l'impression que le fusil à chiens était une amelioration?
Donc c'est quoi la distinction?

Peut-on avoir le reste de la phrase ? Peut-être que c'est suivi d'un qualificatif qui indique une spécificité de ces chiens ?

Fusil à broche désigne probablement un fusil tirant des cartouches à broche,alias cartouches Lefaucheux. Fusil à chiens est probablement par opposition à fusil à percuteur.
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartouche_%C3%A0_broche
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chien_(arme)

@FrançoisJurain  Parce qu'il n'y aurait pas de percuteur sur un fusil à chien? Bizarre ! mais je ne suis pas spécialiste !

@FrançoisJurain Wikipedia :  Le percuteur peut être frappé : dissocié du chien (que l'on appelle alors marteau) ou inclus sur le chien (percuteur frappé) ou lancé. Par contre il existe des chiens à mèche, des chiens à silex, des chiens à broche... (Wikipedia)

Vous avez raison: 'pinfire', ou 'fusil à broche' utilise les cartouches Lefaucheux. Et quel nom heureux our une arme à feu!

C'est peu probable, mais il y a 'le Remington Rolling-block'. Je n'ai jamais vu une exemplaire, mais le premier fois que j'ai vu une photo, j'ai eu la nette impression qu'il a deux chiens (l'un derriere l'autre) et apparemment l'arme était connu en France ...
